# Read more-less in ol tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was making read more-less toggle with jquery, which would appear after 100th symbol in text.

Right now i have code that does that with 100th symbol in html of OL tag. It works just like i want, but 100th symbol in markup is not the same as in text, because it counts tags too.

```
var showChar = 100;
var ellipsestext = "...";
var moretext = "Ещё";
var lesstext = "Скрыть";

$('.more').each(function () {
    var content = $(this).html();
    if (content.length > showChar) {
        var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
        var h = content.substr(showChar, content.length - showChar);
        var position = h.indexOf('</li>');
        var h = [h.slice(0, position), '</span></li><span class="morecontent">', h.slice(position + 5)].join('');
        var html = c + '<span class="moreellipses">' + ellipsestext + '</span><span class="morecontent"><span>'
            + h + '</span><a href="" class="morelink">' + moretext + '</a></span>';
        $(this).html(html);
    }
});

$(".morelink").click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass("less")) {
        $(this).removeClass("less");
        $(this).html(moretext);
        $('.morecontent').each(function() {
            $(this).css('display', 'none');
        });
        $('.moreellipses').css('display', 'inline');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("less");
        $(this).html(lesstext);
        $('.morecontent').each(function () {
            $(this).css('display', 'inline');
        });
        $('.moreellipses').css('display', 'none');
    }
    return false;
});
```

I tried to determine the position of 100th symbol in text in html, by getting substring from text, but substring might appear sooner in html, or even be broken by tags. 
Is there a way to modify my code, so that 'ellipsestext' would appear after 100th symbol in text?

Comment: Update for clarification.
Let me try to rephrase what i want. Code above puts ...More after 100th symbol in HTML. As you can see i take html().length, but it counts tags too. For example, length of html like this "<li>text</li>" is 13 (if i am not mistaken). But i want ...More to be after 100th symbol in text(). I cannot change html() calls in my code to text() ones, because, as you can see in code above, i need to change html markup of <ol> element, iserting my spans.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using also `$(this).text()` to keep track of the remaining 'available' characters and on each iteration, you should update that value. 
Then to know in which position you are going to insert your markup you can go searching the `indexOf` the substring that you'll show

Something like:

```
const maxShowChar = 100;
let showChar = maxShowChar;
const ellipsestext = "...";
const moretext = "Ещё";
const lesstext = "Скрыть";


$('.more').each(function () {
    var textContent= $(this).text();
    var content = $(this).html();
    if (textContent.length > showChar) {
    [...]
    const textC = textContent.substr(0,showChar);
    const c = content.substr(0, content.indexOf(textC));
    [...]
    }else{
    showChar = showChar - textContent.length;
    }
});
```

Comment: A: markup i have there looks like this:

<ol>
<li>large text</li>
<li>more text</li>
</ol>

and ...More button should appear not after <li> element, but in the middle of it.

B: I can't use text(), because i need to change <ol> markup, adding closing <li> tag and so on. I understand, that i need to insert ...More after 100th symbol in text(), but how to determine, where is this symbol in html()?

Comment: If I understood correctly, Do you want to add a [ ... more] after the li element if it has more than 100 characters and cut the content to that limit?

Could you attach an HTML markup example of what you're using?

Comment: Before any changes i made it looked like this: https://prnt.sc/m5s1t6
Now it looks like this: https://prnt.sc/m5s3a7, - and works properly, but "...Ещё"-opening button is placed in a wrong place. It has to be further in a text.
To be clear, it's user who determines what would be in <ol> tag. I simply render what is stored in DB to the page.